# Replace the attribute rel with href using jQuery - preserve the value

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

I have more links such:

```
<a rel="custom_link1_to_large_image">thumb</a>
```

Is there a way to preserve the links and have instead href:
    href="custom_link1_to_large_image"

I need to have it working with a lightbox nad I do not have the ability to add that manually as are auto-generated by NextGen from WP.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

Above will make all links from:

```
<a rel="custom_links">..</a>
```

Become

```
<a rel="custom_links" href="custom_links">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('a[rel]').attr('href', function() {
    return $('this').attr('rel');
}).attr('rel', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it more like this:

```
$('a[rel]').attr('rel',function(i,rel){ this.href = rel; return null; });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/xnyr5/

If you want to retain the `rel`, just remove the `return null;`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks a bit more complex but it worked. Looking at the other answers, those should work too.

Comment: @Lucian - You're welcome. It probably looks complex because it's on one line. Break up the body of the function with line-breaks, and it probably looks a little cleaner. If you were not looking to get rid of the `rel` attributes, I'd change it [to this](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/xnyr5/1/): `$('a[rel]').attr('href',function(){return this.rel;});`